# Creating new access table with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is a simple question but I can't find a straightforward answer anywhere for some reason. I am very new to VBA and Access but am learning quickly. I have used VBA to export data from access to Excel, then manipulate in excel, and now my results are in Excel. (just one row of numbers, and then a few other numbers placed here and there.) Because I can't import a chart from Excel to access, I need to move the results back over to access so I can do my work there.

I need help with how to, using VBA, create a new table, with say one field for the row of data, and then 3 fields for the other results. Then I can use that table to create my graph.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

***First result in google...***

To import a Microsoft Excel file in Microsoft Access 7.0

- Save the file in Microsoft Excel using standard database formatting listed above. Close the file.
- Start Microsoft Access 7.0 and open the database you want to import the Microsoft Excel information into.
- On the File menu, click Get External Data and then click Import.
- From the import dialog box, choose Microsoft Excel (*.xls) for the Files Of Type option.

This will display only the Microsoft Excel files.
Find the desired file and click the Import button.
The Import Spreadsheet Wizard appears and allows you to choose options specific to the file.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141228

Comment: Should you really really really want to use VBA, of which I don't see the point, see the answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911049/access-vba-unable-to-create-table?rq=1